# Vue. How to pass a variable I have on server (process.env.SERVER) to the browser

Tags: vue.js

On the frontend server I have a file I can read with:

```
if(!!process.env.SERVER) {
  require("dotenv").config( { path: '/hw/.env', debug: true } )
  console.log(process.env.myvar)
}
```

But how can I pass the vlue of `process.env.myvar` to the browser?

Thanks.

Comment: When you mean "frontend server" do you mean in your VueJS application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get some variables for all cases you can create an enviroment file with just `.env` as the name next to `package.json` in your project.

To get variables from that file you need to declare them first in the `.env` like this:

```
VUE_APP_MYVAR = 'myvar'
```

In your app you can use it like this:

```
process.env.VUE_APP_MYVAR
```

---

If you need some variables depending on the `process`, respectively for your enviroment, your `myvar` can't be called with `process.env.SERVER`. If `SERVER` is the process, you need a `.env.server` file next to your `package.json`.

You can then, again, declare `myvar` in `.env.server` like this:

```
VUE_APP_MYVAR = 'myvar'
```

To get `process.env.VUE_APP_MYVAR` this time you have to ensure, that you `build` or `serve` your enviroment named `server`. Else, your app trying to get `process.env.VUE_APP_MYVAR` with the process you used.

For Example: If you have `.env.development` and `.env.server`, both can contain `VUE_APP_MYVAR = 'myvar'` with different assigned values. Which one is picked depends on the enviroment you `build` or `serve`.

For more information, see the docs: [Modes and Environment Variables
#Modes](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)